# Running HQL from Camel Hibernate Componenet

Tags: hibernate, hql, apache-camel

Is there any example to execute HQL directly from Camel Hibernate component?
I have looked into examples given [here](http://camel.apache.org/hibernate.html) .But could not find anything related to running HQLs. Please Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not supported by Camel Hibernate component.

You can use [Camel JPA](http://camel.apache.org/jpa.html) instead. Page contains also examples. If you use Hibernate as wrapped implementation HQL can be used in consumers namedQuery and query.

Answer (score 1):

It's not documented, but you can do it like that:

```
<from uri="hibernate:com.example.Foo?consumer.query=from com.example.Foo order by id"/>
```

I'm doing that with with Camel 2.14.1.